# Quick Maths grammar question - How to write a domain of $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, discrete-mathematics, terminology

A function $f(x) = k$ and the domain is $\{-2,-1,\dotsc,3\}$. Would I say 
$$x = \{-2,-1,\dotsc,3\}\quad\text{or}\quad x \in \{-2,-1,\dotsc,3\} \ ?$$
Thanks.

Comment: One alternative is $f: \{-2,-1,...,3\} \rightarrow B$ where B is the set that f maps to as you're trying to describe the domain of the function f itself, not the domain of x

Comment: You definitely would not say $x = \{-2,-1,\ldots,3 \}$.  I would say, "The domain of $f$ is $\{-2,-1,\ldots,3 \}$."  (By the way, I think your formula should be either $f(x) = x$ or $f(k) = k$.)

Comment: Neither of your statements "$x = \{-2,-1,\dots,3\}$" or "$x \in \{-2,-1,\dots,3\}$" is a clear/typical way to say what the domain of your function $f$ is.

Comment: So what would be?

Comment: The first is definitely wrong.  The second one is okay depending on the context.  e.g., you can write "For $x \in \{-2, -1, \ldots, 3\}$ define $f(x) = 3x$ " and this is clear.

Answer (score 2):

Your second alternative is the correct one.

The value of $x$ is not a *set* of numbers, rather it is *in a set* of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to look at it:

When you write $x = \lbrace -2, -1, \dotsc ,3\rbrace$ you are saying "$x$ is equal to the set consisting of the integers $-2$ through $3$".  If $x$ were really a set then you'd be fine, but if you want to say that the set consists of the possible values for $x$, that is it's the domain of $f$, then saying $x = \lbrace -2, -1, \dotsc ,3\rbrace$  isn't true.  When you write $x \in \lbrace -2, -1, \dotsc, 3\rbrace$ you are saying "$x$ is an element of the set consisting of the integers $-2$ through $3$" which is correct.

Comment: Okay, so this is true? f(x) ∈ {.... Whatever the output values are}

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Sorry I meant f(x)∈ {k < f(x) < z}

Comment: Writing $\lbrace k < f(x) < z\rbrace$ is very ambiguous.  For example does it mean "the set of $x$ such that $f(x)$ is between $k$ and $z$" or does it mean "the set of outputs for $f$ which lie between $k$ and $z$".  It's not clear from what you've wrote.  The first statement could be written as $\lbrace x \mid k < f(x) < z\rbrace$ and the second statement could be written as $\lbrace y = f(x) \mid k < y < z\rbrace$.

Comment: I wish to say the range for y is between say 2 and 10... or I can just say (2 < f(x) < 10)

Comment: If $y$ only takes on integer values then you could write the range as $\lbrace y\in \mathbb{Z}\mid 2 \le y \le 10\rbrace$.  You could also say $y\in \lbrace 2,3,\dotsc,10\rbrace$.

Comment: Also, that first "statement" - Would it read: y is in the real set such that 2<y<10? Does the brackets have to go on the outside? Or could you write it with them after the "∣"?

Comment: $\lbrace y\in \mathbb{Z}\mid 2 \le y \le 10\rbrace$ is read as "the set of integers $y$ such that $y$ is greater than or equal to $2$ and less than or equal to $10$."  Yes, the brackets need to go on outside.

Comment: Okay - Is this the "proper" way - Even to hand write?

Comment: It is certainly the least ambiguous, so generally yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to be formal you can say that the domain of $f(x)$ is $\{x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid -2 \leq x \leq 3\}$.

Comment: I see - So I can say f(x) ∈ {.... Whatever the output values are}

Answer (score 0):

Use $\in$.  And be careful with your commas:  $\{-2, -1 \color{red}, \dots \color{red}, 3\}$

In general:

$x \in S$ means "$x$ is an element of $S$" or "$x$ is in $S$."  (The $\LaTeX$ code to produce "$\in$" is `$\in$`.)

$x = s$ means "$x$ is $S$" or "$x$ is equal to $S$."  In this case you would be saying $x$ **is** the domain, but this is not what you want to say.